# Display the content of a page, which have some ACf field, on an other page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I try without success to display the content of a page which have some ACF field on an other page. The website is built with Wordpress.
I try the query posts solution but it doesn't consider the ACF field of the page.

Thank you
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access ACF fields on another page, use

the_field('my_field_name', $id);

where $id is the page ID of the other page or post.

Comment: Hi Thomas, would you mind marking the answer as correct? I get bonus StackOverflow points for that :-)